# For some reason I can't close forms in my if statement?

Tags: vb.net

So, I'm trying to close all forms in my app when the user reverts their settings via clicking a button, but it isn't going well, as for some reason when I try to close them nothing happens.

I have checked for output and didn't notice anything, and strangely, if I close my forms without an if statement, it works. What's up?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to revert all your settings? There is no undo, and if you click yes, WikiFinder will restart.", "WikiFinder", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
        My.Settings.MenuColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(248, 24, 0)
        My.Settings.MenuTextColor = Color.White
        My.Settings.Siggy = ""
        My.Settings.Save()
        WebForm.Close()
        ForumSiggy.Close()
        URLform.Close()
        MenuForm.Close()
        Me.Close()
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The answer to YesNo is Yes or No, not OK.

Comment: 30 seconds in the debugger would give you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not entering the `If` block because your dialog is Yes/No not OK. Use

```
result= DialogResult.Yes
```

This would be easy to determine by debugging.